# Structure & Channel Forms not playing nicely

Tags: channel, channel-form, module, structure, php-errors

I'm using a new installation of EE (2.8.1) with the latest Structure version.

I have a channel which allows entries to be submitted by the front-end user.  However, when an entry is submitted via the front-end, it throws these errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Channel_form_lib::$EE

Filename: structure/ext.structure.php

Line Number: 651

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: structure/ext.structure.php

Line Number: 651

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: structure/ext.structure.php

Line Number: 651

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Channel_form_lib::$EE

Filename: structure/ext.structure.php

Line Number: 669

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: structure/ext.structure.php

Line Number: 669

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: structure/ext.structure.php

Line Number: 669

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Channel_form_lib::$EE

Filename: structure/ext.structure.php

Line Number: 683

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: structure/ext.structure.php

Line Number: 683

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: structure/ext.structure.php

Line Number: 683

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: hidden

Filename: structure/ext.structure.php

Line Number: 730

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /nfs/c08/h01/mnt/148871/domains/slddev.sarahlynndesign.com/html/ac/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 447
```

The entry is submitted, but it will not take me to the required location after submission, or will it send out an email notification.

Comment: Did you end up finding a fix for this? Having the same problem../

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this issue too but managed to fix it by doing the following:

- Go to Addons > Modules > Structure
- Click Module Settings in the top right
- On this screen click the `convert to using the 2.7 hooks` link (bottom option) and then press Save Module Settings

This worked fine for me however I'm not sure of any implications it may have?

Comment: This did the trick for me recently when I had this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the suggested code? http://buildwithstructure.com/documentation/safecracker/

Comment: I was about to hit you guys up too. Do you have an updated `exp:channel:form` example?

Comment: Yes, using any of this does not help at all.

Comment: Adding a me too to this one. Getting the exact same error. Was there a resolution to this problem? All front end channel forms were working prior to a recent EE v2.8.1 upgrade. Also using Structure v3.3.14.5. Super urgent that this get fixed. Will post report in buildwithstructure tender forums too.